# Restrict available instance types in GCE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How can I restrict instance types in Google Compute Engine?

For instance, how can I make it that a set of users can only create "micro" instances?  *Or* that instances in a certain project can only be "micro"?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. Some policies are available on Compute Engine (https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints), but this one does not appear in the list.

Comment: Using IAM Conditions seems like the correct technique, but I do not see a way to specify a condition on `request.machineType`. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We currently have a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/158524244) for this in the works. A Few customers requested this in the past, so we might see something like this being rolled out in the near future. Note, there are no ETA's Feature Requests.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't answer your question before because I worked on [an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-preserve-your-innovation-speed-and-your-budget-with-quotas-apis-d20557d191ab). It has been release today and I explain in it how to set quotas on different product.

If you have a closer look to the Compute Engine part, you can limit the number of CPU usable per family type and thus achieve what you want. It's not "machine type", only "CPU type". But allow only 1 N1 CPU in 1 region, you meet almost the same requirement!